# Android: Getting previous date in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

i'm successfully displaying the DatePickerDialog with restricting the previous date by using `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`. In this case it not activating the previous dates and restricting the previous months but user still able to select the previous date of present month (For understanding see the image and code)

[image]

```
etDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(EventMyEventEdit.this, new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                     mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                     mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                     mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
                     String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
                     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

                     etDate.setText(sdf.format(mcurrentDate.getTime()));

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Edit: I want to restrict the user when selecting the previous dates than the present date

Comment: What is your question? Are you suggesting that there's a bug in DatePickerDialog?

Comment: This varies on all devices. You will have to check user input yourself.

Comment: @egor: I want to restrict the user,when selecting the previous date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and resolve it by changing theme of DatePickerDialog.I dont know why it depends on theme in my case but it worked for me

use following code

```
 DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, datePickerListener, myear, mmonth,
                        mday) {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        view.setSpinnersShown(true);
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                        if (year < myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    }
                };
```

Comment: It's working bro, Thank you for your explanation (Regarding theme).

Comment: @kiran happy to hear that

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dhiraj. I solved the issue by changing the code as Dhiraj suggestion

**imports**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
```

**Code**

```
etDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        EventMyEventEdit.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, new OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

                                etDate.setText(sdf.format(mcurrentDate.getTime()));

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);


                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - 10000);

                datePickerDialog.show();

            }
        });
```